# Tests using embedded postgres fail with Illegal State Exception

Tags: java, postgresql, gitlab-ci

I'm running some tests against an embedded postgres database using otj-pg-embedded. While the tests run fine locally they fail when run by Gitlab-CI with an Illegal State Exception. 
Gitlab CI builds it and runs tests that don't include otj-pg-embedded just fine.

I've commented out most of the test class and pinpointed the problem to:

```
public static SingleInstancePostgresRule pg = EmbeddedPostgresRules.singleInstance();
```

```
import com.goldfinger.models.AuditLog;
import com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.FlywayPreparer;
import com.opentable.db.postgres.junit.EmbeddedPostgresRules;
import com.opentable.db.postgres.junit.PreparedDbRule;
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SQLAuditRepositoryTest {

    private static SQLAuditRepository sqlAuditRepository;
    private static AuditLog auditLog_1;
    private static AuditLog auditLog_2;
    private static AuditLog auditLog_3;
    private static List<AuditLog> auditLogList;

    @ClassRule
        public static SingleInstancePostgresRule pg = EmbeddedPostgresRules.singleInstance();


    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
        assert (2 == 2);
    }
}
```

This is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process [/tmp/embedded-pg/PG-06e3a92a2edb6ddd6dbdf5602d0252ca/bin/initdb, -A, trust, -U, postgres, -D, /tmp/epg6584640257265165384, -E, UTF-8] failed

    at com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres.system(EmbeddedPostgres.java:626)
    at com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres.initdb(EmbeddedPostgres.java:240)
...
... many lines here
...
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: java:latest
services:
  - postgres:latest
before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

package:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assemble

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - ./gradlew check
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit: build/test-results/test/*.xml
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to stop the Embedded Postgress running in the background other than computer restart. It help to resole this problem.

Comment: I had the same problem with macOS 12.1 Monterey and the problem seems to be that the binaries for postgres throw a "segmentation fault" error. Ricardo's comment and this discussion seem to help: https://github.com/opentable/otj-pg-embedded/issues/163#issuecomment-956335779

Answer (score 21):

### If stopped after upgrading to macOS 11.x+ (to BigSur)

For Mac users (especially the new BigSur), there's already an [issue](https://github.com/opentable/otj-pg-embedded/issues/136) open for this problem.

There's not yet a definitive "fix", but I've got things working by installing `postgresql` via:

```
brew install postgresql
```

Not sure if the same applies to other OS.

Comment: worked. thanks. Big Sur has broken several things :)

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar problem running tests with embedded postgres on MacOS M1:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process [/var/folders/g_/jxzv9glj0p13njlzpr9xtcfm0000gn/T/embedded-pg/PG-4f38c8a8b2500189835f8ec1b75de81b/bin/initdb, -A, trust, -U, postgres, -D, /var/folders/g_/jxzv9glj0p13njlzpr9xtcfm0000gn/T/pg-embedded-009358be-3e95-4dbe-aa7a-01a9008511cb-3277843270072134584/epg524445573999525527, -E, UTF-8] failed
```

I copy pasted the command and run it on shell:

```
/var/folders/g_/jxzv9glj0p13njlzpr9xtcfm0000gn/T/embedded-pg/PG-4f38c8a8b2500189835f8ec1b75de81b/bin/initdb -A trust -U postgres -D /var/folders/g_/jxzv9glj0p13njlzpr9xtcfm0000gn/T/pg-embedded-009358be-3e95-4dbe-aa7a-01a9008511cb-3277843270072134584/epg524445573999525527 -E UTF-8
```

and the output show me a hint:

```
Running bootstrap script ... 2021-02-17 08:18:21.008 WET [28692] FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Cannot allocate memory
2021-02-17 08:18:21.008 WET [28692] DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=56, 03600).
2021-02-17 08:18:21.008 WET [28692] HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded your kernel's SHMALL parameter.  You might need to reconfigure the kernel with larger SHMALL.
    The PostgreSQL documentation contains more information about shared memory configuration.
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/folders/g_/jxzv9glj0p13njlzpr9xtcfm0000gn/T/pg-embedded-cbe6f5f8-24b2-4431-afec-6e7aeb1dbb5d-8656684715588054403/epg6904898061245880853"
```

Then I run on shell:

```
sudo sysctl kern.sysv.shmmax=104857600
sudo sysctl kern.sysv.shmall=25600
```

And it worked.

Comment: This is a good hint for debugging, and in my case it showed me the above answer about macos problems will help. I got this after invoking the command: `dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libpq.5.dylib`

Comment: @Innokenty how do you get through this error?

Answer (score 3):

In macOS 12.1 Monterey, I solved the same issue by downloading the postgres binaries and letting `EmbeddedPostgres` resolve those as I describe [here](https://github.com/opentable/otj-pg-embedded/issues/163#issuecomment-1010987745)

```
# download binaries, here for postgres 12.9
curl -O http://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-12.9-1-osx-binaries.zip --output-dir /tmp/

# unzip it in /tmp/
unzip /tmp/postgresql-12.9-1-osx-binaries.zip -d /tmp/postgresql-12.9-1-osx-binaries/
```

then in the code:

```
import com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres;
import java.io.File;

EmbeddedPostgres pg = EmbeddedPostgres
  .builder()
  .setPgDirectoryResolver(
     dir -> new File("/tmp/postgresql-12.9-1-osx-binaries/pgsql/"))
  .start();
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem with flyway/embedded-pg. Seems that the temp files are getting corrupt at some point. Reboot will fix it (until it happens again) or you can delete `PG-*` directory inside `/tmp/embedded-pg/`

Answer (score 2):

Windows users could have a similar problem.
My situation was when tried run integration test for embedded postgres:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process
> [C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded-pg\PG-02224a4f280160581d2144dec70deaf8\bin\initdb.exe,
> -A, trust, -U, postgres, -D, C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Temp\epg7146074401943849308, -E, UTF-8]
> failed

When try run this command from the terminal you will get a problem with dll library similar to below:

> error while loading shared libraries: msvcr120.dll: cannot open shared
> object file: no such file or directory

To solve this, Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 should be installed.
You can find it from the official [microsoft site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly the same problem, but created db like this:

```
EmbeddedPostgres.builder()
            .setDataDirectory(Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("target")
                    .resolve("data-dir-parent")
                    .resolve("data-dir")))
            .start();
```

But data-dir must be unique per test, so process was failing, due to 'not empty dir'.
If you are also setting directories manually, try some suffix for 'data-dir',
for example `.resolve("data-dir" + UUID.randomUUID())`

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was a missing environment variable (`LC_ALL`).

Obviously, the stacktrace does not deliver all information necessary to tackle the problem.

As causes are numerous, my general advice is to capture stdout to gather more information, like so:

```java
EmbeddedPostgres.builder()
    .setOutputRedirector(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.to(new java.io.File("/tmp/stdout.log")))
    .start()
```